# Manipulate csv data using bash

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed, formatting

I have a CSV file with several rows and columns, some rows have 4 columns and some have 5 columns. I want to add to those with 4 columns, one more column so all the rows have 5 columns. The info that I must add must be in the 3rd row, or at the end.
The CSV file looks like this:

```
name;ip;supplier;os;manufact
```

How can this be done in bash?

Comment: What's your question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please, post some sample data with related expected output and sjoe some work done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `read` to split the CSV, then output the desired number of columns.

```sh
cat test.csv | while read line; do
  IFS=\; read -ra COL <<< "$line"
  echo "${COL[0]};${COL[1]};${COL[2]};${COL[3]};${COL[4]};"
done
```

For example, with test.csv containing:

```
1;2;3;4
1;2;3;4;5
1;2;3;4;
1;2;3;4;5;
```

The above script outputs:

```
1;2;3;4;;
1;2;3;4;5;
1;2;3;4;;
1;2;3;4;5;
```